# Not supported proxy scheme None

Tags: proxy

i have installed python 3.7 from anacoda. not able to install any new packages through pip or conda. environmental variables,proxy etc are configured. but still iam getting following error

raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Not supported proxy scheme None

did any body resolved this error?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. You can see [over here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9216) a description of the issue.

To solve it you have basically to specify your proxy settings with an `http://` scheme in front. So in windows you would do:

```
set http_proxy=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
set https_proxy=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
```

After that you can simply do your usual `pip install package` and it should work.